# Excel C# COM addon returning an array with Dates and Doubles

Tags: c#, excel, interop, format, time-series

My C# Excel addon is transforming a time series into another time series.

Time series is defined as a two column range with the first column being date and second column being a floating point number.

Though my C# code is returning back DateTime for date, the Excel converts it into Excel date represented by integer and the displayed value is the integer, e.g. 39000, not a date format, e.g. 14/12/2012.

Thus, the user has to press CTRL + # to turn it into dates.

Is there a way somehow return the output of a C# excel addon already Excel formatted as Date?

Comment: I think you need to rework your question... once you say "addon returning an array with dates and doubles" and then you say excel converts DateTime to what??

Comment: thanks for feedback. have reformatted.

Comment: Dates in COM are a floating point number, the number of days since January 1st, 1899.  So 39000 is about right.  Sounds to me like the default format of the cells is just wrong.

Comment: Yes, exactly, the question is whether i can return apart from the numbers also the format somehow???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Format the cells from the code which returns the values. E.g. if you have a handle to the range object, you can do something like `range.NumberFormat="yyyy-mm-dd"`.

b) Pre-format the cells to a date format before running the code which imports the data. This would work if the same sheet is used each time, rather than a blank or arbitrary sheet.

c) This is an ugly hack, but try returning your date values as strings, formatted as "mm/dd/yyyy". This should force Excel to interpret the values as dates. AFAIK the machine locale settings will not affect the translation in this case.

Answer (score 1):

To supplement Adam's c) answer:
If you have a Date/Time variable and return it to a cell from a Sub using Range.Value it will format the cell as a date (tested using VBA rather than C#: not sure if .Value is available using interop?) 
If you use Range.Value2 it will NOT format the cell as a date.
If you try to do this from a UDF the UDF will NOT change the formatting of the cell.